# Teaching Quantifiers Before Logical Connectives

Tags: undergraduate-education, curriculum, logic

In this short question, I would like to ask whether it is possibly good to teach quantifier before logical connectives in a logic introduction lecture?

I know there is a relationship between them but my question is based on my observation that students usually already get the concept of existential quantifier. Before introducing them to more complex forms of statement, maybe they can understand basic form of quantifier statements first (of course, after introducing open and closed sentence). This is just an idea. Let me know if anyone has done this because I have never seen one.

Thank you very much!

Comment: What level is this at? Are these math majors in an upper-division course? By "logic introduction lecture" do you mean the introductory lecture in a semester-long course on formal logic, or do you mean an introductory lecture on the first day of a class on some other topic such as topology, where you want to give them some preliminary foundation in logic? You could point out to your students that they have already seen statements that have implicit quantifiers, as when they learned axioms of the real number system such as $x+y=y+x$.

Comment: I think it does make sense to introduce quantifiers before complex logical expressions, because you can rely on the student's familiarity from English (or whichever is their 1st language): "All men are mortal," "Some birds do not fly," etc.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke Yes. I have been thinking about that.

Comment: @BenCrowell Undergraduate math major education. Right after they enter uni, we have an introductory set and logic course (as in highschool there is none).

Comment: For existential quantifier, I think they understand it better easily like there is an integer x such that x^2 - x - 6 = 0 and they can find the x. Now they just need to write the argument in a neat way. Even for universal statement (although the domain must probably be limited to finite set most of the times)

Comment: @21understanding: When someone asks you to clarify a question, it's better to edit the question rather than replying in comments.

Comment: A little more advanced (but avoids necessity of any background mathematical knowledge) is avoiding quantifier scope ambiguities in natural language, such as *every student speaks two languages* AND *every student did not pay attention* AND *every researcher of a company gave a presentation* AND *everyone drank tea or coffee* AND *If a die is rolled twice, then what is the probability that each die showed either 2 or 5?* It could be instructive to indicate how each of these can have more than one interpretation. But this may be more advanced than your intended audience is ready for.

Answer (score 1):

A strategy I once adopted while teaching logic for philosophers at the undergraduate ( 1st year) level

(1) introducing connectives with the motivation of explaining set operations and set relations

(2) working with connectives on non explicitly quantified open sentences to prove some set theoretic basic laws ( using truth tables or natural deduction )

(3) finally introducing explicit quantification to make the proofs rigorous.

Comment: Thanks. It is quite (maybe the most?) common too in teaching logic to math. I am indeed considering the quantification first and wondering whether it is possible.